# Slot Machine Code Not Working Yet Has No Error Message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm new to coding and attempting to code a Discord bot.  I've been trying to run a slot machine code over the past few days.  Nothing I do seems to make the code run, and even when it does run, it won't work yet gives no error code.  I've tried to Google it, but it's kind of hard to Google something when there isn't (supposedly) an issue.

I've tried re-arranging the coding, I've tried placing "message.channel.send" in there or triggering it with the prefix + "slots", I've tried different emojis and instead used the custom ones from our testing server, and I've tried with and without brackets/braces.

The code I'm using for the slots game:

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  let slots = [":Dratini:", ":Mankey:", ":Snorlax:"];
  let result1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * slots.length));
  let result2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * slots.length));
  let result3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * slots.length));
  let name = message.author.displayName;
  let icon = message.author.displayAvatarURL;

  if (slots[result1] === slots[result2] && slots[result3]) {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
       .setFooter('You won!', icon)
       .setTitle(':slot_machine: Slots :slot_machine:')
       .addField('Result:', slots[result1] + slots[result2] + slots[result3], true)
       .setColor(0xF4E842)
    message.channel.send(embed);

  } else {
    let embed2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
       .setFooter('You lost!', icon)
       .setTitle(':slot_machine: Slots :slot_machine:')
       .addField('Result:', slots[result1] + slots[result2] + slots[result3], true)
       .setColor(0xF4E842)
    message.channel.send(embed2);
  }
}
```

I expect the slot game to randomize the emojis and when all 3 of them are the same, post an embedded message in Discord saying they've won (or post one if they lost).  Instead, I don't even receive an error message and the bot doesn't play the game.  (The ":Dratini", ":Mankey:", & ":Snorlax:" are the custom emojis for the server.)

Comment: how are you importing and calling the function?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure if I even am.  I was following a tutorial I found (which probably doesn't work anymore)...  Here it is, if that helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUf1wScwGF0  (I'm just starting coding, I'm sorry!)

Comment: Yep, the mistake is there in the tutorial. With instrumental music in the background instead of any sort of explanation. I'd recommend against learning from Retro Development.

Comment: Okay, I'll avoid them (my bad, I read that wrong).  By the way, I did try those adjustments and they didn't work, but thank you though, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
  if (slots[result1] === slots[result2] && slots[result3]) {
```

it's wrong syntax. Should be something like:

```
  if (slots[result1] === slots[result2] && slots[result1] === slots[result3]) {
```

Although, with the `slots` array containing no duplicates, you could simplify it to

```
  if (result1 === result2 && result1 === result3) {
```